# Python/wxPython: Doing work continuously in the background

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, background

I'm making a program for running simulations in Python, with a wxPython interface. In the program, you can create a simulation, and the program renders (=calculates) it for you. Rendering can be very time-consuming sometimes.

When the user starts a simulation, and defines an initial state, I want the program to render the simulation continuously in the background, while the user may be doing different things in the program. Sort of like a YouTube-style bar that fills up: You can play the simulation only up to the point that was rendered.

How should I run the rendering function?

Answer (score 10):

I would use a `threading.Thread` to run the code in the background and `wx.CallAfter` to post updates to my window thread to render them to the user.

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=self.do_work)
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()

...

def do_work(self):
    # processing code here
    while processing:
        # do stuff
        wx.CallAfter(self.update_view, args, kwargs)

def update_view(self, args):
    # do stuff with args
    # since wx.CallAfter was used, it's safe to do GUI stuff here
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a fair bit of info on the [wxPython wiki about long running tasks](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) that might be useful.  They basically make use a thread and `wx.PostEvent` to handle communication between the thread and the main wx event loop.

Answer (score 4):

Launch a new process to render in background and periodically check to see if it has returned.

You can find the documentation for the subprocess module [here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) and the multiprocess module [here](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocess#module-multiprocessing).  As Jay said, multiprocess is probably better if you're using Python 2.6.  That said, I don't think there would be any performance difference between the two.  Multiprocess just seems to be a wrapper around subprocess making certain things easier to do.

While subprocess/multiprocess is the standard way to do this, you may also want to take a look at [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/15/30/#API).

Comment: I've never worked with multiple processes before. Where do I start? Also, I understood there are different ways of doing it. Which one should I choose?

Comment: N.B., keep in mind that since this is a program for doing simulations, performance is very important.

Comment: If you can use python 2.6, I believe the multiprocessing module would be the standard way of accomplishing this. It should give you just as much performance as your OS and hardware has to provide.

Comment: FYI if you're using Windows with wxPython, it's better to use 2.5 http://lists.wxwidgets.org/pipermail/wxpython-users/2009-March/085022.html

Comment: I also heard about Stackless Python. Is it relevant? Is it better than subprocess/multiprocess?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a very slightly different approach, you can have a look at [stackless](http://www.stackless.com/) python and create a tasklet for your rendering process. I find it very easy to use personally.